# Can I print all the values (from a column) that start with the same word?

Tags: python, printing, return-value, datagridviewcolumn

[These are the values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6Hgi.png)

I have all these values from a certain column in a data frame, and as you can see, the second and third value start with the same word "Sicilian" (I know there are more values). I'd like to print all the values from that column that start with the same word. I'm working in python.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can loop to every value

I will create dict to example

first loop to every value
and use the [str.startswith](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/startswith) function

```py
data = {"mark1":"tommy","Unkown":"data","mark2":"john","mark3":"Nick","not someone":None} # our data

marks = [] # the list that we going to append if the value_y starts with (x)

for mark in data:
    # returns False if the mark doesn't starts with "mark" else returns True
    if mark.startswith("mark"): # check if the mark starts with "mark"
        marks.append((mark,data[mark]))
print(marks)
```

you can even do it in one line

```py
[marks.append((mark,data[mark])) if mark.startswith("mark") else None for mark in data]
```

Comment: Thank you! but I'm looking for the code of extracting such values from column in a data frame, not from a list. I tried implementing this but I couldn't do it.

Comment: @Raoulfr oh, I am sorry. try other ways like recursive functions or rearrange the data